# joomla 2.5 module translation issue

Tags: module, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I am working on joomla 2.5.4. I am unable to install language for my module please see following my mod_staker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install SYSTEM "http://dev.joomla.org/xml/1.5/module-install.dtd">
<install version="1.5" type="module" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Stalker</name>
    <author>Nick Texidor</author>
    <authorEmail>nick@texidor.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.nicktexidor.com/</authorUrl>
    <creationDate>8 November 2009</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2008-2009 Nick Texidor. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU/GPL</license>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <description>Displays icons for your online social networking sites.</description>

    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_stalker.ini</language>
    </languages>

    <files>
        <filename module="mod_stalker">mod_stalker.php</filename>
        <filename>gpl.txt</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>

        <filename>assets/index.html</filename>
        <filename>assets/css/index.html</filename>
        <filename>assets/css/stalker.css</filename>

        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>

    </files>

    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">

        <field name="moduleclass_sfx" type="text" default="" label="MODSUFFIX" description="MODSUFFIXDESC" />

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="iconsize" type="list" default='32' label="ICONSIZELABEL" description="ICONSIZEDESC">
        <option value='16'>16px</option>
        <option value='20'>20px</option>
        <option value='24'>24px</option>
        </field>
        <field name="digg" type="list" default='0' label="DIGGOPTLABEL" description="DIGGOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="diggname" type="text" default='' label="DIGGNAMELABEL" description="DIGGNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="diigo" type="list" default='0' label="DIIGOOPTLABEL" description="DIIGOOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="diigoname" type="text" default='' label="DIIGONAMELABEL" description="DIIGONAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="facebook" type="list" default='0' label="FACEBOOKOPTLABEL" description="FACEBOOKOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="facebookname" type="text" default='' label="FACEBOOKNAMELABEL" description="FACEBOOKNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="facebookgrp" type="list" default='0' label="FACEBOOKGRPOPTLABEL" description="FACEBOOKGRPOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="facebookgrpname" type="text" default='' label="FACEBOOKGRPNAMELABEL" description="FACEBOOKGRPNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="facebookpage" type="list" default='0' label="FACEBOOKPAGEOPTLABEL" description="FACEBOOKPAGEOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="facebookpagename" type="text" default='' label="FACEBOOKPAGENAMELABEL" description="FACEBOOKPAGENAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="feedburner" type="list" default='0' label="FEEDBURNEROPTLABEL" description="FEEDBURNEROPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="feedburnername" type="text" default='' label="FEEDBURNERNAMELABEL" description="FEEDBURNERNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="flickr" type="list" default='0' label="FLICKROPTLABEL" description="FLICKROPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="flickrname" type="text" default='' label="FLICKRNAMELABEL" description="FLICKRNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="friendfeed" type="list" default='0' label="FRIENDFEEDOPTLABEL" description="FRIENDFEEDOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="friendfeedname" type="text" default='' label="FRIENDFEEDNAMELABEL" description="FRIENDFEEDNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="friendster" type="list" default='0' label="FRIENDSTEROPTLABEL" description="FRIENDSTEROPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="friendstername" type="text" default='' label="FRIENDSTERNAMELABEL" description="FRIENDSTERNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="hi5" type="list" default='0' label="HI5OPTLABEL" description="HI5OPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="hi5name" type="text" default='' label="HI5NAMELABEL" description="HI5NAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="hyves" type="list" default='0' label="HYVESOPTLABEL" description="HYVESOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="hyvesname" type="text" default='' label="HYVESNAMELABEL" description="HYVESNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="jaiku" type="list" default='0' label="JAIKUOPTLABEL" description="JAIKUOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="jaikuname" type="text" default='' label="JAIKUNAMELABEL" description="JAIKUNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="kwippy" type="list" default='0' label="KWIPPYOPTLABEL" description="KWIPPYOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="kwippyname" type="text" default='' label="KWIPPYNAMELABEL" description="KWIPPYNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="lastfm" type="list" default='0' label="LASTFMOPTLABEL" description="LASTFMOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="lastfmname" type="text" default='' label="LASTFMNAMELABEL" description="LASTFMNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="lastfmart" type="list" default='0' label="LASTFMARTOPTLABEL" description="LASTFMARTOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="lastfmartname" type="text" default='' label="LASTFMARTNAMELABEL" description="LASTFMARTNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="linkedin" type="list" default='0' label="LINKEDINOPTLABEL" description="LINKEDINOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="linkedinname" type="text" default='' label="LINKEDINNAMELABEL" description="LINKEDINNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="linkedingrp" type="list" default='0' label="LINKEDINGRPOPTLABEL" description="LINKEDINGRPOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="linkedingrpname" type="text" default='' label="LINKEDINGRPNAMELABEL" description="LINKEDINGRPNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="meetup" type="list" default='0' label="MEETUPOPTLABEL" description="MEETUPOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="meetupname" type="text" default='' label="MEETUPNAMELABEL" description="MEETUPNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="metacafe" type="list" default='0' label="METACAFEOPTLABEL" description="METACAFEOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="metacafename" type="text" default='' label="METACAFENAMELABEL" description="METACAFENAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="misterwong" type="list" default='0' label="MISTERWONGOPTLABEL" description="MISTERWONGOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="misterwongname" type="text" default='' label="MISTERWONGNAMELABEL" description="MISTERONGNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="myspace" type="list" default='0' label="MYSPACEOPTLABEL" description="MYSPACEOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="myspacename" type="text" default='' label="MYSPACENAMELABEL" description="MYSPACENAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="netvibes" type="list" default='0' label="NETVIBESOPTLABEL" description="NETVIBESOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="netvibesname" type="text" default='' label="NETVIBESNAMELABEL" description="NETVIBESNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="newsvine" type="list" default='0' label="NEWSVINEOPTLABEL" description="NEWSVINEOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="newsvinename" type="text" default='' label="NEWSVINENAMELABEL" description="NEWSVINENAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="ning" type="list" default='0' label="NINGOPTLABEL" description="NINGOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="ningname" type="text" default='' label="NINGNAMELABEL" description="NINGNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="orkut" type="list" default='0' label="ORKUTOPTLABEL" description="ORKUTOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="orkutname" type="text" default='' label="ORKUTNAMELABEL" description="ORKUTNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="photobucket" type="list" default='0' label="PHOTOBUCKETOPTLABEL" description="PHOTOBUCKETOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="photobucketname" type="text" default='' label="PHOTOBUCKETNAMELABEL" description="PHOTOBUCKETNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="picasa" type="list" default='0' label="PICASAOPTLABEL" description="PICASAOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="picasaname" type="text" default='' label="PICASANAMELABEL" description="PICASANAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="plurk" type="list" default='0' label="PLURKOPTLABEL" description="PLURKOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="plurkname" type="text" default='' label="PLURKNAMELABEL" description="PLURKNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="qik" type="list" default='0' label="QIKOPTLABEL" description="QIKOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="qikname" type="text" default='' label="QIKNAMELABEL" description="QIKNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="reader" type="list" default='0' label="READEROPTLABEL" description="READEROPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="readername" type="text" default='' label="READERNAMELABEL" description="READERNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="reddit" type="list" default='0' label="REDDITOPTLABEL" description="REDDITOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="redditname" type="text" default='' label="REDDITNAMELABEL" description="REDDITNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="simpy" type="list" default='0' label="SIMPYOPTLABEL" description="SIMPYOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="simpyname" type="text" default='' label="SIMPYNAMELABEL" description="SIMPYNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="stumbleupon" type="list" default='0' label="STUMBLEUPONOPTLABEL" description="STUMBLEUPONOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="stumbleuponname" type="text" default='' label="STUMBLEUPONNAMELABEL" description="STUMBLEUPONNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="technorati" type="list" default='0' label="TECHNORATIOPTLABEL" description="TECHNORATIOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="technoratiname" type="text" default='' label="TECHNORATINAMELABEL" description="TECHNORATINAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="tumblr" type="list" default='0' label="TUMBLROPTLABEL" description="TUMBLROPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="tumblrname" type="text" default='' label="TUMBLRNAMELABEL" description="TUMBLRNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="twitter" type="list" default='0' label="TWITTEROPTLABEL" description="TWITTEROPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="twittername" type="text" default='' label="TWITTERNAMELABEL" description="TWITTERNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="vox" type="list" default='0' label="VOXOPTLABEL" description="VOXOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="voxname" type="text" default='' label="VOXNAMELABEL" description="VOXNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="vimeo" type="list" default='0' label="VIMEOOPTLABEL" description="VIMEOOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="vimeoname" type="text" default='' label="VIMEONAMELABEL" description="VIMEONAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="xbox" type="list" default='0' label="XBOXLIVEOPTLABEL" description="XBOXLIVEOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="xboxname" type="text" default='' label="XBOXLIVENAMELABEL" description="XBOXLIVENAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="xing" type="list" default='0' label="XINGOPTLABEL" description="XINGOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="xingname" type="text" default='' label="XINGNAMELABEL" description="XINGNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="youtube" type="list" default='0' label="YOUTUBEOPTLABEL" description="YOUTUBEOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="youtubename" type="text" default='' label="YOUTUBENAMELABEL" description="YOUTUBENAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="" description=""></field>

        <field name="extlink" type="list" default='0' label="EXTLINKOPTLABEL" description="EXTLINKOPTDESC">
        <option value='0'>No</option>
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        </field>
        <field name="extlinkname" type="text" default='' label="EXTLINKNAMELABEL" description="EXTLINKNAMEDESC"></field>

        <field name="cache" type="list" default="1" label="CACHE" description="CACHEDESC">
            <option value="1">USEGLOBAL</option>
            <option value="0">NOCACHE</option>
        </field>
        <field name="cache_time" type="text" default="900" label="CACHETIME" description="CACHETIMEDESC" />
      </fieldset>
    </fields>
    </config>
</install>
```

and this is following my language file `en-GB.mod_stalker.ini`

```
MOD_STALKER=mod_stalker
BEBOOPTLABEL=Enable Bebo
BEBOOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Bebo
BEBONAMELABEL=Bebo username
BEBONAMEDESC=Enter your Bebo username


FRIENDSTEROPTLABEL=Enable Friendster
FRIENDSTEROPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Friendster
FRIENDSTERNAMELABEL=Friendster Id
FRIENDSTERNAMEDESC=Enter your Friendster Id

HI5OPTLABEL=Enable Hi5
HI5OPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Hi5
HI5NAMELABEL=Hi5 Username
HI5NAMEDESC=Enter your Hi5 username

HYVESOPTLABEL=Enable Hyves
HYVESOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Hyves
HYVESNAMELABEL=Hyves Username
HYVESNAMEDESC=Enter your Hyves username

JAIKUOPTLABEL=Enable Jaiku
JAIKUOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Jaiku
JAIKUNAMELABEL=Jaiku Username
JAIKUNAMEDESC=Enter your Jaiku username

KWIPPYOPTLABEL=Enable Kwippy
KWIPPYOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Kwippy
KWIPPYNAMELABEL=Kwippy Username
KWIPPYNAMEDESC=Enter your Kwippy username

LASTFMOPTLABEL=Enable Last.fm
LASTFMOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Last.fm
LASTFMNAMELABEL=Last.fm Username
LASTFMNAMEDESC=Enter your Last.fm username

LASTFMARTOPTLABEL=Enable Last.fm Artist
LASTFMARTOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Last.fm Artist
LASTFMARTNAMELABEL=Last.fm Artist Name
LASTFMARTNAMEDESC=Enter your Last.fm Artist Name

LINKEDINOPTLABEL=Enable LinkedIn
LINKEDINOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to LinkedIn
LINKEDINNAMELABEL=LinkedIn Username
LINKEDINNAMEDESC=Enter your LinkedIn username

LINKEDINGRPOPTLABEL=Enable LinkedIn Group
LINKEDINGRPOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to a LinkedIn Group
LINKEDINGRPNAMELABEL=LinkedIn Group Id
LINKEDINGRPNAMEDESC=Enter your LinkedIn Group Id

MEETUPOPTLABEL=Enable MeetUp
MEETUPOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to MeetUp
MEETUPNAMELABEL=MeetUp Username
MEETUPNAMEDESC=Enter your MeetUp username

METACAFEOPTLABEL=Enable Metacafe
METACAFEOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Metacafe
METACAFENAMELABEL=Metacafe Username
METACAFENAMEDESC=Enter your Metacafe username

MISTERWONGOPTLABEL=Enable MisterWong
MISTERWONGOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to MisterWong
MISTERWONGNAMELABEL=MisterWong Username
MISTERWONGNAMEDESC=Enter your MisterWong username

MYSPACEOPTLABEL=Enable MySpace
MYSPACEOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to MySpace
MYSPACENAMELABEL=MySpace Username
MYSPACENAMEDESC=Enter your MySpace username

NETVIBESOPTLABEL=Enable Netvibes
NETVIBESOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Netvibes
NETVIBESNAMELABEL=Netvibes Username
NETVIBESNAMEDESC=Enter your Netvibes username

NEWSVINEOPTLABEL=Enable Newsvines
NEWSVINEOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Newsvine
NEWSVINENAMELABEL=Newsvine Username
NEWSVINENAMEDESC=Enter your Newsvine username

NINGOPTLABEL=Enable Ning
NINGOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Ning
NINGNAMELABEL=Ning Username
NINGNAMEDESC=Enter your Ning username

ORKUTOPTLABEL=Enable Orkut
ORKUTOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Orkut
ORKUTNAMELABEL=Orkut Userid
ORKUTNAMEDESC=Enter your Orkut userid

PHOTOBUCKETOPTLABEL=Enable Photobucket
PHOTOBUCKETOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Photobucket
PHOTOBUCKETNAMELABEL=Photobucket Username
PHOTOBUCKETNAMEDESC=Enter your Photobucket username

PICASAOPTLABEL=Enable Picasa
PICASAOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Picasa
PICASANAMELABEL=Picasa Username
PICASANAMEDESC=Enter your Picasa username

PLURKOPTLABEL=Enable Plurk
PLURKOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Plurk
PLURKNAMELABEL=Plurk Username
PLURKNAMEDESC=Enter your Plurk username

QIKOPTLABEL=Enable Qik
QIKOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Qik
QIKNAMELABEL=Qik Username
QIKNAMEDESC=Enter your Qik username

READEROPTLABEL=Enable Google Reader
READEROPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Google Reader
READERNAMELABEL=Google Reader Id
READERNAMEDESC=Enter your Google Reader Id.

REDDITOPTLABEL=Enable Reddit
REDDITOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Reddit
REDDITNAMELABEL=Reddit Username
REDDITNAMEDESC=Enter your Reddit username

SIMPYOPTLABEL=Enable Simpy
SIMPYOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Simpy
SIMPYNAMELABEL=Simpy Username
SIMPYNAMEDESC=Enter your Simpy username

STUMBLEUPONOPTLABEL=Enable StumbleUpon
STUMBLEUPONOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to StumbleUpon
STUMBLEUPONNAMELABEL=StumbleUpon Username
STUMBLEUPONNAMEDESC=Enter your StumbleUpon username

TECHNORATIOPTLABEL=Enable Technorati
TECHNORATIOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Technorati
TECHNORATINAMELABEL=Technorati Username
TECHNORATINAMEDESC=Enter your Technorati username

TUMBLROPTLABEL=Enable Tumblr
TUMBLROPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Tumblr
TUMBLRNAMELABEL=Tumblr Username
TUMBLRNAMEDESC=Enter your Tumblr username

TWITTEROPTLABEL=Enable Twitter
TWITTEROPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Twitter
TWITTERNAMELABEL=Twitter Username
TWITTERNAMEDESC=Enter your Twitter username

VIMEOOPTLABEL=Enable Vimeo
VIMEOOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Vimeo
VIMEONAMELABEL=Vimeo Username
VIMEONAMEDESC=Enter your Vimeo username

VOXOPTLABEL=Enable Vox
VOXOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to Vox
VOXNAMELABEL=Vox Username
VOXNAMEDESC=Enter your Vox username

XBOXLIVEOPTLABEL=Enable Xbox Live
XBOXLIVEOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to your Xbox Live Profile
XBOXLIVENAMELABEL=Xbox Live Username
XBOXLIVENAMEDESC=Enter your Xbox Live Gamer Tag

XINGOPTLABEL=Enable Xing
XINGOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to your Xing Profile
XINGNAMELABEL=Xing Username
XINGNAMEDESC=Enter your Xing username

YOUTUBEOPTLABEL=Enable YouTube
YOUTUBEOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to YouTube
YOUTUBENAMELABEL=YouTube Username
YOUTUBENAMEDESC=Enter your YouTube username

EXTLINKOPTLABEL=Enable External Link
EXTLINKOPTDESC=Select YES to display a link to an External Site
EXTLINKNAMELABEL=External Link URL
EXTLINKNAMEDESC=Enter the URL of the External Link

CACHE=Caching
CACHEDESC=Select whether to cache the content of this module.
USEGLOBAL=Use global
NOCACHE=No caching
CACHETIME=Cache Time
CACHETIMEDESC=The time before the module is recached.
```

its unable to translate labels for config they are defined in language file module right panel still showing like `CACHETIMEDESC` instead of `The time before the module is recached.`

Comment: You failed to provide any necessary details: **how** does it fail? Do you get an error? What happens? At the same time, you provided a lot of unnecessary garbage, like the whole XML of the module...

Comment: i have updated question, actually joomla didn't translate translation variable like showing `ICONSIZEDESC` instead of `some text`

Comment: in joomla admin panel where i am going to configure module right side of panel

Comment: @ppeterka did you see updated question

Comment: Is the .ini file in the right folder?

Comment: yes i have checked its in language\en-GB\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable translation debuging, check if your language file is loaded correctly. or is joomla trying to load it from another folder?

Another thing but i think it is not the reason for your translation problem is that you specify a **dtd** for **Joomla 1.5** but the content of your xml is 1.6 style and target of your module 2.5. Any XML validator should show you some errors.

Comment: can you please tell me how dtd for joomla 2.5

Comment: too bad, there is no newer dtd. I ask this long time ago for 1.6/1.7 at the offical forum, but nothing happens. Correct me if they added the dtd somewhere. I think is better to add no dtd in the xml file instead of an mismatching one.